# Give an example of a relation $R$ on the given set $A$ that has the properties described: $A=\mathbb Q$, $R$ is both symmetric and anti-symmetric

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

$A=\mathbb Q$,  $R$ is both symmetric and anti-symmetric

What I have is "$R = \{(a, b)~ |~ a, b \in \mathbb Q~ ,~ a = b\}$". I just want to double check if my logic is correct and if not, figure out how to properly make an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works. Let's check it:

(1) Is $R$ symmetric?

A relation is symmetric if $(a, b) \in R \implies (b, a) \in R$. Take an arbitrary element of the relation you proposed. We have $(x, x) \in R$, where $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. There's nothing to check, since $(x, x) = (x, x) \in R$.

(2) Is $R$ antisymmetric?

A relation is antisymmetric if $(a, b) \in R \implies a = b$. Again, an arbitrary element of the relation you proposed is of the form $(x, x)$, and $x = x$. So $R$ is antisymmetric.

Comment: I have one more question because one of the problem's wordings is confusing me. It follows the same instructions of "Give an example of a relation R on the given set A that has the properties described.  If such an example is not possible, explain why not." The question says "A=∅, R is not an equivalence relation." I'm confused on how to go about writing a relation that is not an equivalence relation.

Comment: If $A$ is empty, the relation $R$ must also be empty (there are no elements of $A$!). Therefore $R$ vacuously satisfies the requirements of an equivalence relation: reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity. There's nothing to check.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help